# How to customize stopword list in Lucene 4.4

Tags: java, lucene, stop-words

I'm using Lucene 4.4 to analyze a small corpus. I've tried StopAnalyzer and StopAnalyzer. However, many terms that I don't need still show up in my result. For example, "I'll", "we", "x", etc. So, I need to customize the stopword list provided by Lucene. My questions are:

1. How do I add new stopwords? 
   I know that Lucene has this constructor to use a customized stopwords

   public StopAnalyzer(Version matchVersion, CharArraySet stopWords)

   But I don't want to build stopword from scratch. I want to use the existing stopwords, and just add extra stopwords that I need.
2. How can I filter out all the numbers, both as word and literal numbers, such as "1", "20", "five" , "ten", etc ?

**My solution**

1. As femtoRgon showed, the stopword list provided by Lucene is very small and cannot be changed. I created a CustomizeStopAnalyzer that takes a list of stopwords.
   I use StandardTokenizer and chain a few filters together.
2. To remove numbers, I have to add a NumericFilter class that check every token to see if it's numeric.
   Many thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1 - The standard stop word set is `StopAnalyzer.ENGLISH_STOPWORD_SET`.  It is unmodifiable, so you should just copy the code as a starting point:

```java
 final List<String> stopWords = Arrays.asList(
   "a", "an", "and", "are", "as", "at", "be", "but", "by",
   "for", "if", "in", "into", "is", "it",
   "no", "not", "of", "on", "or", "such",
   "that", "the", "their", "then", "there", "these",
   "they", "this", "to", "was", "will", "with"
 );
 final CharArraySet stopSet = new CharArraySet(Version.LUCENE_CURRENT, 
     stopWords, false);
```

2 - A stop filter isn't the right approach for this.  I suspect, you are probably looking for something like [`LetterTokenizer`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_1_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/core/LetterTokenizer.html), which will define tokens as consecutive strings of letter, thus eliminating any non-letter characters.

Comment: Thanks femtoRgon. Not only do I want to filter non-letter character, but also I want to filter word that means numbers, such as "five, ten, fifty", etc. While using NLTK, I could check every token and have a method to check if the token contain any digit or if it can be parsed to a float. I don't know if something similar can be done in Lucene?

Comment: I've tried LetterTokenizer, it solves one problem but create another problem. It strips off numbers and punctuations. As the result, I get tokens like "isn, didn, ll, ve", which are not caught by stopword list. Keep adding these strings into the stopword list is not a very good solution. StandardTokenizer can recognize "isn't, I'll" etc. as tokens but it doesn't remove numbers. Do you have any suggestion to fix it? Thanks,

Comment: I'm not aware of any filters that do exactly what you are looking for.  You'll probably need to implement your own.  Since you are just intending to remove tokens, [`FilteringTokenFilter`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/util/FilteringTokenFilter.html) would be the base class to implement.  You'll just need to implement the `accept` method, then incorporate it into your analyzer.